# If charged in two separate states, what determines which state has priority?

Tags: united-states

If someone were to commit crimes such as murder in two different states and both states file charges against the person, which state processes the case? More specifically, can someone who is charged in a state without a death penalty be extradited to another state with the death penalty?

Answer (score 2):

If the suspect is in custody in a state in which he is charged, that state has priority. That state may opt to allow another state to prosecute first.

If the suspect is in custody in a state where he is not charged, it is up to that state who gets him first.

A suspect can be extradited from a state without a death penalty to a state that has one.